# How can I login to two django applications with a single access credential?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-sessions

I currently have several applications developed in django, and they ask me that with a single credential and depending on the permissions assigned to each user, they can access the different applications, how could I do that taking into account the session management middleware what does django have?

Comment: to make it easy why not put your several applications in one project ?

Comment: I do not want it to become a monolith, since each application is big on its own

Comment: so you can create an api for login and registration using django REST Framework .

Comment: How could I authenticate a user through an API? Do you have a page I can check?

Comment: try to see on your youtube or in google you can find a course on API using Django.The idea is to everytime a user enter his username and password for logging. you can send it to api to check whether that User exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to become monolith, you must create an Auth service that handles permission, credentials, scopes and etc. This service should communicate to two other services for granting access or check permissions and stuffs like that.
Take a look at [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)